# How to pip install different subdirectories from same repo?

Tags: airflow, python-packaging, pip-tools

I have an installation of Airflow in my `requirements.in` file `-e git+git@github.com:apache/airflow.git#egg=apache-airflow` and I want another line that will install the backport providers Google package with a cherry picked commit from my own fork.

`-e git+git@github.com:myfork/airflow.git#egg=apache-airflow&subdirectory=airflow/operators/google` but when compiling the requirements (piptools) I get an error saying that `apache-airflow/airflow/providers/google` cannot be found.

How can you pip install from the same repo under different directories? e.g. one for the full Airflow installation and the second for just the backport package under `airflow.providers.google`

Comment: Is that a pip-tools issue? What do you mean by "compiling the requirements"? Maybe fix the tags if it is not an issue related to pip itself.

Comment: @sinoroc yes, piptools. Edited the tags.